Trying to install an Archer TBE55E WiFi 7 Bluetooth 5.4 PCIe Adapter on Linux Mint
Greetings all I am trying to install an Archer TBE550E WiFi 7 Bluetooth 5.4 PCIe Adapter into my system on ASUS X570plus motherboard. I have scoured the internet to find linux software to no avail. My onboard wifi still works but I am trying to upgrade the technology for future use. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I might install this to work in linux. I am new to this so I apologize if I have not posted anything in the right form. All help is appreciated. Thank you in advance. Kevin

Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu are on-topic here, refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Linux Mint forum. (One advantage of Ubuntu is its many support options, you opted for Linux Mint so take advantage of its support options, or SE Unix & Linux found in the on-topic link)

FYI:  Don't forget that drivers are actually kernel modules; thus the kernel stack you're using matters. You didn't provide your release detail, so we don't even know what possibilities are open for you, as if using a Ubuntu LTS release, you have kernel stack choice with the default set by your install media. When you ask at an appropriate site for your chosen OS, don't forget to say what you're running (Linux Mint have Ubuntu and Debian based systems; you only mention Linux Mint with specifics).
